# Access function return type as Tuple in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, tuples

Its a really naive question but I haven't used tuples before so asking this out.
I am facing some issue while accessing a function return value which is a tuple in another function.

Here is my code :

```
  public Tuple<string, string, string> CreateTransaction()
        {
            var tCompResp = new Tuple<string, string, string>(T, TCode, Message);
            return tCompResp;
}
```

Now I am not sure how can I access this return values of above function in other page

```
  var tResp = new Tuple<string, string, string>((objManager.CreateTransaction()).Item1, (objManager.CreateTransaction()).Item2, (objManager.CreateTransaction()).Item3);
```

In Above line I am could access the return tuple but problem is I am calling same function ( CreateTransaction() ) 3 times

**So my question is how can I get function's tuple return value in single call?**

```
 String tRespon = objManager.CreateTransaction()   ///Suppose if return type is string.
```

I will use this value in another function like this

```
Update(tRespon.Item1, tRespon.Item2, tRespon.Item3);
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but personally I'd write a simple wrapper class rather than using a tuple. Tuples are not very readable - the term `Item1` doesn't convey much meaning.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson but if over this problem by properly commenting the code like  ///item1: Response Code; item2: response Text  etc.

Comment: Note that normally it's easier to create the tuple through `Tuple.Create(x, y, z)` if the types of x, y, z are the exact types you need. In this way you don't have to write the `<...>` part. If ony one or two need different types, you can cast them explicitly (necessary even if you have `null` values): `Tuple.Create((SomeType)x, (SomeOtherType)null, z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Tuple<string,string,string> tRespon = objManager.CreateTransaction();

Update(tRespon.Item1,tRespon.Item2,tRespon.Item3);
```

`CreateTransaction` returns `Tuple<string,string,string>` not `string`

always you can use `var` instead `Tuple<string,string,string>`

```
var tRespon = objManager.CreateTransaction();
```

Note that `var` is just another way to write it, not a type.

but better way should be using new class to return this data:

```
public class ConnectionInfo
{
   public string T;
   public string Code;
   public string Message;
}

public ConnectionInfo CreateTransaction()
{
     var tCompResp = new ConnectionInfo{T=T, Code=TCode, Message=Message};
     return tCompResp;
}
```

then

```
var tRespon = objManager.CreateTransaction();
Update(tResp.T, tResp.Code, tResp.Message);
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to create a new Tuple:

```
   var tResp = objManager.CreateTransaction();
   Update(tResp.Item1, tResp.Item2, tResp.Item3);
```

`CreateTransaction()` already returns a `Tuple` that you can use right away

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter:

```
var tRespon = objManager.CreateTransaction();
Update(tRespon.Item1,tRespon.Item2,tRespon.Item3);
```